# How to switch boot sequence in dual boot PC?

Tags: wifi, dual-boot, grub, internet

Fellas
I've been using Linux Mint for quite some time & recently have replaced my Windows partition with Elementary OS. But the Boot sequence hasn't changed. I want to make Elementary my default OS instead of Linux Mint.

I checked all the options listed but without success. I googled it, the problem is everyone is either suggesting to bypass or install some utility. As far as I understand, it shouldn't be. The question is how to? What's the procedure?

- Have wi-fi adapter which isn't being recognized by Elementary (RTL8188FTV).
  Is there any run around or some utility needs to be installed?

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Find out how to install grub customizer via ppa and there are also tutorials on YouTube which explain how to use it. Much easier than editing the grub.cfg.

Comment: Hi
Sysadmin

Thanks, it has worked like charm
My PC is back to its default startup, the way I wanted
Thanks again